# Creating a Python Command Prompt

Tags: python

I am currently making a python program that will execute commands to the command prompt via the os import. I want it to show the current file directory like the normal command prompt does, but I can't manage to do that. It only shows the directory that the program is located at. If I try changing directories via the cd command while running the python cmd, it doesn't change directories.

How can I use the cd command with my python command prompt and have it show the directory that I'm currently in (not the one the program was run from)?

```
import os

def main():
    input = raw_input("\n" + os.getcwd() + ">")
    execute(input)

def execute(c):
    os.system(c)
    main()

print("--Python Command Prompt--")
os.system("color c");
main()
```

Comment: Try  `print(__file__)`

Comment: tried that already. didn't change the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change directories while running the python script, try :

```
def execute(c):
    if(c.split()[0]=="cd"): #if command is cd
        if(len(c.split())>1): #if a directoy was specified, change to that
            os.chdir(c.split()[1])
        else: #otherwise change to home directory
            os.chdir(os.path.expanduser("~"))
    else:
        os.system(c)
    main()
```